# Eager load a list of entries, then only the first asset, from the first block type

Tags: eager-loading

I would like to eager load:

1. A list of entries
2. Within the entries loop, the first image, from the first of a block type on a matrix field.

**Loading the entries like this**

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
  sectionId: 12,
  with: [
    'pageContent.text:text',
    ['pageContent.images:images', {
      withTransforms: [{
        width: 100,
        height: 100
      }]
    }]
  ]
}) %}
```

**Loading the images:**

Currently, I can only seem to load an image like this:

````
{% for block in entry.pageContent %}
  {% if block.type == 'images' %}
    {% if img is not defined %}
      {% set img = block.images[0] ?? null %}

  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}```
````

I cannot seems to filter the query to the matrix down like you can when getting a matrix normally, I just receive a bunch of errors, I am trying  something like:

```
{% set img = entry.content.type('images').first.images[0] ?? null %}
```

Additionally, it appears I cannot use the loop to save a variable to use outside of it, I presume this is intentional and how eager loading works. If that is the case, would I even benefit from any optimisation on the query at all if it is looping on blocks I do not need? As an example, I would normally do something like

```
{% set img = entry.content.type('images').first.images.first ?? null %}
```

Following on from whether this is worth it... I also want to get a text field on this matrix (from the first of a block type again), but, in another position in the template. Does this mean I need to do another loop again to get the data specifically for another field?

Is there a better way to deal with this?

I hope that makes sense, let me know if not I'll do my best to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

> Additionally, it appears I cannot use the loop to save a variable to use outside of it

This is really a separate question. Answering it anyway: you need to give the variable some value before the loop, and then it works:

```
{% set img = null %} {# initial value #}

{% for block in entry.pageContent %}
  {% if block.type == 'images' %}
    {% if not img %}
      {% set img = block.images[0] ?? null %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{# img will be the first image of first 'images' block, or null #}
```

Answer (score 0):

This article may be helpful to you: [Speed up your Craft CMS Templates with Eager Loading](https://nystudio107.com/blog/speed-up-your-craft-cms-templates-with-eager-loading)

Basically, when you eager load the Matrix blocks, you're no longer getting an ElementCriteriaModel, rather you're getting an array pre-loaded with the Matrix blocks. That's why you can't do something like `entry.pageContent.type('images').first.images`